# How to change the look of displaying items of the <struts: checkboxlist >

Tags: struts2

In the Struts2 application in the jsp page I have a feild where the user can select what ever option he want , i used struts:checkboxlist like this

```
<s:checkboxlist name="cust.communityList" label="Are You Inteterested In"  
    list="{'WebSpere Consultuing','Portal Consulting','SOA/BPM Consulting','Content Management',
       'DataPower Consulting','Information Management Services','Application Monitoring','Application Security',
       'Migration to WebSphere','Application Testing','WebSphere Version Upgrade','JAM/Panther Consulting','IBM Software Procurement','XMLink/Progressions','Other'}" />
```

It is working fine . But in the browser it's look is not good , It dispalying the list elements in a row wise one after the other ,then in the next row ....

I wanted to display them ,2 in the first row ,next 2 items in the second row ans so on ...

How can i display the checkboxlist items in that way ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just did this via the custom template method. It seemed to get the job done. Look at the docs to see how to pull the original checkboxlist FreeMarker css code into your own project. In summary, pull `struts2.core.jar/template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl` into your own webapp/template directory and modify it. I make the following changes:

1: at the top of the file, where the iterator tag is, I added the following lines (not the iteratorline) before and after:

```
<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<@s.iterator value="parameters.list">
    <#if itemCount % 3 = 0 > 
        <tr>
    </#if>
    <td>
```

2: At the end of the file, where the iterator ends, I added:

```
<#if itemCount % 3 = 0 > 
    </tr>
</#if>
</@s.iterator>
</table>
```

3: That's it. Really, the tutorial tells you what you need to know, it's just a matter of hacking up the FreeMarker code.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme for the checkbox OR you can extend the theme and then change it.

Look in your /template/simple/checkboxlist.ftl for the base checkboxlist template.

For info on overriding templates see: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/template-loading.html